# Datalife engine - where are the functions in .tpl files called from?

Tags: php, smarty, datalife-engine

I'm migrating my blog from wordpress to datalife engine. For what i figured it out by searching, is writen in smarty php... I never worked with it before and i want to query the database to implement something on the theme... But i can't write it on the tpl files...

What i want to know is, where are functions like {rating}, {content} or [related-news] declared...

i want to query the database, but for what i know, i can't do it on the tpl files direcly.

And i can't find any info where they are because all the readme files of datalife are in russian. Can someone help me to figure out how is this structure done?

Answer (score 0):

Datalife Engine use the module files in folder /engine/modules/ to define which .tpl files to use for which function, so there is no single file that declare all tpl files, you have to check which module or which function you want to edit, in your case it seems like you are looking for full page of content which in DLE called "fullstory" the module that handle this module is engine/modules/show.full.php and the theme file to use for this module are fullstory.tpl to dispaly the rest of fullstory, addcomment.tpl for add comment form and relatednews.tpl to display related news, about {rating} there are at least 3 modules use this tag which are show.short.php, show.custom.php and show.full.php, however the DLE structure is each module use its own tpl file to display as {content}, I think if you go to dlestarter.com you can get all answer you need from them, I think they are not so advanced team but they do speak English so they can help you more effectively to any questions you may have...good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Datalife Engine does not use smarty template engine!.
It has it's on custom engine.
The Flow of the cms its simple, every article has a short story and optionally a full story.
In the template folder you have a bunch of tpl files with build up the final page.
main.tpl beeing the file called for every page you display.
Now typically once you call the front page the main.tpl along with shortstory.tpl are called along with other blocks for the front page.
the shortstory.tpl is build by the /engine/modules/show.short.php file witch will call the db for the data or memcached if enabled and the data was cached replace the the engin tags with the necessary data like {title} and many others.
You should really look at the documentation to undestand witch tags are found in witch section.
One important think to note is that you cannot add php in the tpl files at least not out of the box but you can include files with php in them.
I recommend heading over to dlestarter.com they are a good reference for documentation in English and pretty much the only once as well. They also have a forum where i look into sometimes.